# Internet Explorer Website Support

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am developing a website that uses a lot of jQuery and I have found that making sure everything works with Internet Explorer is a pain. How do professionals deal with this problem?

Comment: jQuery is compatible with IE. If youre having problems, its something else - perhaps the javascript code you are writing that utilizes the jQuery. Since picking up jQuery. All my IE woes have been limited to CSS.

Comment: You can encourage your users to upgrade to newer browsers, as [Microsoft has done](http://www.ie6countdown.com/).

Comment: I advice you to forget it about IE7 and down, I think they are completely out of standardize subject(especially IE6 because the war of browsers), and now days, most users use IE8 or up if they don't use browsers more respectable for standardize.

Comment: @Jeff, do you understand that jQuery is far from perfect and that there are well-documented __known__ issues with various clients?

Comment: @jerluc no i dont understand that. anecdotally, i have never run into any significant bugs with jquery. i just searched and found no *well* documented known issues except for one in IE 5.5 and Opera 9.27 - neither of which I consider to be relevant to most common jquery development. Do you have any links to known issues?

Comment: Aside from the one's you just mentiond, most of them have to do with CSS generated by jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility#About_CSS_and_Browser_Compatibility

Comment: A better way to explain it is that jQuery doesn't cure all of IE's ails. They're not necessarily jQuery bugs, but IE bugs that jQuery hadn't or properly found a workaround for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do a lot of cross-browser compatibility and use jQuery too (though I don't find the two in conflict; I suspect that the problem lies elsewhere even if it manifests when jQuery is used).

Are you aware of IE's developer tools?  (press F12)  It works a bit like Firebug or Chrome's developers tools.  Of course, it's not as good.  But still, you can edit code live.

(If you'll describe the sort of errors you encounter, I may have some best practices.)

(jerluc has a point. Contiguous integration is a must -- but I assume you're already doing that.)

Answer (score 2):

By sucking it up and getting used to the pain.

Comment: Or simply ignoring it. Read: **I'm not going to buy a *** Windows machine just for a crappy browser!** :)

Comment: Now if only the big-wigs would buy that excuse...haha

Comment: @WTP i never care about IE6 and IE7 when I develop a site. i don't know if there are people still using IE6 or at least IE7.

Comment: LOTS of corporations are still using IE6 and IE7 internally. These days, I usually fight for 'degraded support' for IE and reference things like Yahoo's browser grading system. It's not too hard to get a site to work in IE in terms of basic functionality. It takes a LOT of work to give IE users the same user experience as those using standards compliant browsers.

Comment: @SIFE I was referring to the fact that most professional web developers use a Mac and have no IE at all.

Comment: This really isn't sensitive or helpful.  The fact is that a lot of clients use IE, and cross-browser compatibility is vital for a great many markets.

Comment: Most professional web developers also use Mac with Parallels for a work-station VM :)

Comment: @WTP most 'professional' web developers have each and every web browser at their disposal. Dealing with the crap that is IE is, alas, a big part of many professional web developers' day. If one is only testing the sites they build on one OS and one browser, then they certainly are not professional (or at least, shouldn't be paid like a professional).

Answer (score 2):

[Continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). There's no reason to develop everything at once and test later. It's usually best to get into a develop-test, develop-test, develop-test, ... sort of pattern to your development cycle.

Additionally, be sure to read release notes on **every** library you use, as there is usually a list of known bugs which becomes invaluable as the development process goes on.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, ad-hoc testing (test manually) is the best you can do.
But, there are some tools that can leverage the work a little bit:

- http://www.webappers.com/2007/07/29/test-your-website-in-different-browsers-and-platforms/

Here's tutti. Yeah, its GREAT:

- http://tuttijs.com/

And of course, Selenium:

- http://seleniumhq.org/

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Tutti looks pretty interesting. And +1 for Selenium!